# Why do my phones require @media's max-width so large?

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

I have a simple script:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body { background-color: red; }
}
</style>
<body>test</body>
```

This works fine on my PC. However, on my phones (both 2 of them), regardless of the browser, it doesn't work. Only when I change the `max-width` to 980px that it changes red. Obviously my phones aren't that large. I try to add this [ruler](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/kwcug/), and while its length is fixed on PC (as a good ruler should be), on my phones it's shrunk.

Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have set a viewport meta tag inside your head tag.
Mobile devices will usually use a virtual viewport to display websites. The meta tag tells the browser how it should display the site on mobile.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The `width=device-width` tells the browser that it should set the virtual viewport to be the width of the device, `and initial-scale=1` sets the default zoom level.

Comment: what is the differences between viewport and virtual viewport?

Comment: The virtual viewport is used to allow zooming on mobile, along with making non mobile optimized sites easier to use on mobile.

Comment: How is it different with normal zooming?

Comment: the web actually uses 2 different viewports, a layout viewport and a visual viewport. You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It contains the information I need: "Mobile browsers render pages in a virtual window or viewport, generally at 980px, which is usually wider than the screen, and then shrink the rendered result down so it can all be seen at once."